# Слишком большой отступ между блоками

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять откуда лишний отступ снизу
[image: screenshot]
  CSS:

```
/*Оформляем комментарии*/ 
.comment_wrap {
border: 1px solid #000000;
   /* border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;*/
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.comment_avatar {
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 70px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.comment_info {
color: #989898;
position: relative;
left: 74px;
top: -50px;
width: 120px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.comment_content {
position: relative;
left: 200px;
top: -88px;
width: 590px;
overflow: hidden;
border-left: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="comment_wrap">
    <div class="comment_avatar">
        <div class="article_profile"><img src="/images/ava2.png" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_info">Amarelle<br />
        <i>'.vtime($user['date_last_entry']).'</i>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_content">Оставляю вот такой коммент)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: через отладчик браузера посмотрите, что дает такой отступ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Откуда отступ:** он «остаётся» от элементов `comment_info` и `comment_content`. То есть, мы их сдвигаем, а место, увы, не исчезает. Попробуйте убрать `position:relative;` у них и это станет заметно.

**Что делать:** использовать `margin-top` вместо `top`, добавив `min_height` для `comment_wrap`, чтобы избежать уменьшения размеров родительского слоя. Хотя, на мой взгляд, лучше всего использовать не позиционирование, а `float:left;`. Я создал [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYJLb/) с двумя этими вариантами.

HTML

```
<div class="comment_wrap">
    <div class="comment_avatar">
        <div class="article_profile"><img src="" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_info">Amarelle<br />
        <i>date</i>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_content">
        Оставляю вот такой коммент)
        <br/>
        Оставляю вот такой коммент)
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Оставляю вот такой коммент) 
        <br/>
        Оставляю вот такой коммент)  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment_wrap">
    <div class="comment_avatar">
        <div class="article_profile"><img src="" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_info">Amarelle<br />
        <i>date</i>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_content">
        Оставляю вот такой коммент)
    </div>
</div>
Пример с float: left
<div class="comment_wrap">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div class=""><img src="" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; float: left;">Amarelle<br />
        <i>date</i>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid black;">
        Оставляю вот такой коммент)
        <br/>
        Оставляю вот такой коммент)
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Оставляю вот такой коммент) 
        <br/>
        Оставляю вот такой коммент) 
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
/*Оформляем комментарии*/ 
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.comment_wrap {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
   /* border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;*/
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.comment_avatar {
padding-top: 1px;
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 70px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.comment_info {
color: #989898;
position: relative;
left: 74px;
top: -50px;
width: 120px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.comment_content {
padding-top: 1px;
position: relative;
left: 200px;
width: 590px;
margin-top: -88px;
overflow: hidden;
border-left: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, теперь все выглядит так, как и предполагалось)